# Is it possible to have different type be inferred based on the params passed?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

Based on this example:

```js
type FooProps = {
 baseProp: string
} & ({
 cb: (value: number) => void;
 selectRange: false
} |
{
 cb: (value: [number]) => void;
 selectRange: true
}
)
```

Then what I am looking to do is, change the type `value` param in `cb`, based on the value of `selectRange`.

I'd like to use it in a React component like so:

```js
const FooComp : React.FC<FooProps> = ({cb, selectRange}) => {
...
if (selectRange) {
 cb([1,2])
} else {
 cb(1)
}
...
}
```

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-bas-26k1zd?file=/src/App.tsx) to demonstrate the issue. And a [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#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) where it works

Comment: But it already works as expected, no ? See [playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wo5d8N)

Comment: But then when I call the `cb` in the component it gives me an impossible type of `number & [number]`.

Comment: I don't get any errors in either playground and they both work as expected?

Comment: @kelly In the sandbox it works as well?

Comment: Oh it doesn't; why doesn't your TS playground include calling the `cb`?

Comment: @kelly it does, line 30

Comment: ‍♂️ I was looking at yossarian's playground. Anyways, I think it might have something to do with the different tsconfigs between codesandbox and the playground.

Comment: I've updated the sandbox tsconfig to match the one on the playground, still same result :/

Comment: Codesandbox has a [known issue](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/942) where the editor version of TS doesn't update, so who knows what it's using.  You're trying to use [destructured discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#control-flow-analysis-for-destructured-discriminated-unions) released in TS4.6, so I'd guess codesandbox is stuck on an earlier version.  It works with current TS, so what should we do with this question? Close it? Answer with "upgrade to TS4.6+"?

Comment: @jcalz the problem is that I'm not using this just in codesandbox, but with VSCode, running version 4.7.3 of typescript and it's giving me the same errors, in a bare test environment with only `react` `react-dom` `typescript` and the respective types.
[Here's](https://github.com/LoyalPotato/typescript-error-repo) a repo I just created with the same environment

Comment: I don't know what to say; if I can't reproduce in the TS Playground I can't easily see the issue.  I'm not likely to install a repo in my local environment.

Comment: @jcalz you don't need to install, you can look at the configs and reproduce locally. I'm just saying that it isn't as direct as just a codesandbox problem.

Comment: I don't really have the wherewithal to set up a new project locally; if I can reproduce by clicking on a link or pasting a single snippet into the playground then great, otherwise it's probably not going to happen.  Maybe someone else will come along who can do this.  Can you triple-check which version of TS you're actually using?  Is there a tsc log somewhere?

Comment: I've checked the vscode output logs and it's using the projects tsserver, which is the version 4.7.3